# Azure's CosmosDB - Use query explorer in python program

Tags: python, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a bunch of JSON files stored in Azure's CosmosDB database. I also have a python program that reads the JSON files. I want to run a query on the Azure's query explorer from python

```
    SELECT VALUE Block 
      FROM c 
      JOIN Block IN c.radar50p01
```

So far what I have in my python program is the following

```
    def getCosmosDBClient():
        # Initialize the Python DocumentDB client
        client = document_client.DocumentClient(Constants.URL, {'masterKey': Constants.KEY})
        return client

    def getCosmosDBColl_link():
        client = getCosmosDBClient()

        db_id = Constants.RADAR_DATABASE_NAME
        db_query = "select * from r where r.id = '{0}'".format(db_id)
        db = list(client.QueryDatabases(db_query))[0]
        db_link = db['_self']

        coll_id = Constants.RADAR_COLL_NAME
        coll_query = "select * from r where r.id = '{0}'".format(coll_id)
        coll = list(client.QueryCollections(db_link, coll_query))
        if coll:
            coll = coll[0]
        else:
            raise ValueError("Collection not found in database.")
        coll_link = coll['_self']

        docs = client.ReadDocuments(coll_link)
        return docs
```

So is there a way  to use the Query above in python so I just get what I need specifically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your query have run successfully in the Query Explorer on Azure portal, you just use the [`client.QueryDocuments(collection_link, query)`](http://azure.github.io/azure-documentdb-python/api/pydocumentdb.document_client.html#pydocumentdb.document_client.DocumentClient.QueryDocuments) method to do your query, as the code below from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-documentdb-python#review-the-code).

> A query is performed using SQL
>
> ```
> # Query them in SQL
> query = { 'query': 'SELECT * FROM server s' }    
>
> options = {} 
> options['enableCrossPartitionQuery'] = True
> options['maxItemCount'] = 2
>
> result_iterable = client.QueryDocuments(collection['_self'], query, options)
> results = list(result_iterable);
>
> print(results)
> ```

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: It works. Thanks! What is the max item count for? I did not include that because it might be something i don't want.